# Vue transition animation of toggling between two components is not smooth

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I've got a problem with Vue transitions.

I made a component to create slide transitions. It takes an `enter-only` prop to disable the leave animation.

The problem is sometimes when i try to toggle between two components, there seems to be a brief moment where both components are present. I'd like to make them replace each other perfectly.

Here's a sandbox demonstrating the issue:

[image: Edit Vue Template]

Comment: Please put your code here in the question.  Do not link to external sites that have your code.  Put the code here.

Comment: Additionally, you should check [Transition Modes](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Modes).

Comment: @zero298 Sorry I'll put my codes in the questions from now on. I used the `out-in` transition mode and it worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as mentioned by @zero298 in the comments, I used the `out-in` [transition mode](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Modes) and since my components don't have a leave animation, it works like a charm.

Comment: Perfect solution!

Answer (score 1):

You could try using Vue.nextTick(). Hide the currently visible component and wait a tick to transition to the other. That would involve more toggles (one for each component) and keeping track of which one is currenly active.

Comment: This would work but using a single flag to toggle the components would be more ideal in my case. If no other solution is found, I'll do this. Thank you.